# how to set function or get value from parameters on select change in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am newer in anguler and want a value on change from select option and want to update status of particular ID. I have setup some code but this is not working. can you help me.
fetch data and get it on data and after that setup a select box

```
<select ng-model="newStatus" ng-change="changeNewStatus(data.id, data.message_status)">
                      <option value="1" ng-selected="data.message_status == 1">New</option>
                      <option value="2" ng-selected="data.message_status == 2">Closed</option>
                    </select>
```

now i want to print it here {{selectedResult}}
below is my controller where i want to call this function

```
app.controller('MessageFetchGrid', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$scope.changeNewStatus = function(msgId, msgStatus){
            $scope.selectedResult = "msg-id="+msgId+" status= "+msgStatus;
    }

});
```

here is my full code

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    if(input) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
    return [];
}
```

});

```
app.controller('MessageFetchGrid', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$http.get('api/v1/loadMessage.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.list = data;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 25; //max no of items to display in a page
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
});
$scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
};
$scope.filter = function() {
    $timeout(function() { 
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
    }, 10);
};
$scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};  
$scope.changeNewStatus = function(msgId, msgStatus){
        $scope.selectedResult = "msg-id="+msgId+" status= "+msgStatus;
}
```

});

Comment: Where is the data coming from?And where are you using the newStatus model value?

Comment: data is coming through ajax in data parameter newStatus model is declare in select options

Comment: What are you currently getting as `selectedResult` in your html?

Comment: currently here is nothing, but i want messge ID and status value on change. after that want to update message status in database using ajax,php @AlexJolig

Answer (score 0):

```
    you can use ng-options directive :
partial:
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected">
      <option value="">Select</optipn>
    </select>
    <span>{{selected}}</span>
  </div>
</div>

js:
var app = angular.module("test", []);
app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'aLabel'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'bLabel'
  }];
}]);
    example 
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaRMPz
```

Comment: how to get change value from this code
 <select ng-model="changeStatus" ng-change="changeNewStatus(data.id)">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                      <option value="1" ng-selected="data.message_status == 1">New</option>
                      <option value="2" ng-selected="data.message_status == 2">Closed</option>
                    </select>

Comment: you can add ng-change="getSelectedValue()" and in your controller ng-model will give you the selected value.
$scope.getSelectedValue = function(){
  console.log("selected value is", selected);
}